# ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am trying to import the `SSAO shader` from three (node modules) as such:

```py
import {SSAOShader} from 'three/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader'`
```

but I am getting:

```py
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    ./node_modules/three/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js
    node_modules/three/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js:9
       6 |  * https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/SSAO
       7 |  *
       8 |  */
    >  9 | THREE.SSAOShader = {
      10 |   defines: {
      11 |     "PERSPECTIVE_CAMERA": 1,
      12 |     "KERNEL_SIZE": 32
```

Linking to `jsm` files is no problem, but linking to the `js` files throws the error.

```py
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
import {SSAOShader} from 'three/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader';
```

Would like to be able to use this library without throwing the error.

Comment: try `npm i three` in the console or `npm i`

Comment: three has already been installed via npm. for some reason it is just not recognizing it in the node modules.

Answer (score 2):

> import {SSAOShader} from 'three/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader';

This line of code is not valid since `SSAOShader` is not a module. For now, you have to convert the file to a module by yourself. At a later point a module version of `SSAOShader` will be available in the `jsm` directory.

`three.js R104`

Comment: any suggestions for converting the SSAOShader to a module?

Comment: Put `import * as THREE from 'three';` at the top of the file and remove the `THREE` namespace from `SSAOShader`. At the bottom of the file you add `export { SSAOShader };`. You can then import the file like other modules and use it (of course without the `THREE` namespace). Something like https://jsfiddle.net/4m8gxkjz/

Comment: But when I remove THREE from the name space it throws the error that variables are undefined (or `Attempted import error: 'SSAODepthShader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')`.

Comment: Sry, you have to show your full code otherwise everything I say is just guesswork. Any chances to share your repo?

Comment: https://github.com/daniellehoo/threejs
Currently getting the error `Attempted import error: 'EffectComposer' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').`

Comment: Sry, I'm afraid your repository is full of errors right now. Please go step by step and start with a simple `three.js` scene without any post-processing. You not even have `three.js` in your dependencies (`package.json`). Besides, the way how you create `SSAOPass` is wrong. You can't add a class derived from `React.Component` to `EffectComposer`.